# How to split all strings in a column AND include prefix in all the new data

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset that has data that was entered in one column that should have been put into three separate columns. I'm hoping to separate it into three columns based on a backslash, but each split must include a character prefix which is only found on the first part of the string, and a character suffix which is only found at the end.

So something like "PC211/212.5(C)/664F" has the prefix "PC", and the suffix "F". The prefix is always 2 letters, and the suffix is always 1, and they are always characters. The prefix is always followed by a numeric code, and the suffix is always preceded by either a number or an end parentheses

My data is in a very large dataframe, so I'd like to be able to call it out by column. Here's a reproducible example of a tiny subset of the data I'm working with:

```
df <- data.frame("code" = c("PC211/212.5(C)/664F", "VC23152(A)/23550F", "PC459/460(B)M", "PC187(A)/664F"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like it to return something like:

```
df_id_like <- data.frame("code" = c("PC211/212.5(C)/664F", "VC23152(A)/23550F", "PC459/460(B)M", "PC187(A)/664F"), 
"code_1" = c("PC211F", "VC23152(A)F", "PC459M", "PC187F"), 
"code_2" = c("212.5(C)F", "VC23550F", "PC460(B)M", "PC664F"), 
"code_3" = c("PC664F", NA, NA, NA), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I think the solution may need regex, but am totally open to a solution that doesn't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `tidyr` option using `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(code, paste0("code_", 1:3), sep = "/", fill = "right", remove = F)
#                 code     code_1   code_2 code_3
#1 PC211/212.5(C)/664F      PC211 212.5(C)   664F
#2   VC23152(A)/23550F VC23152(A)   23550F   <NA>
#3       PC459/460(B)M      PC459  460(B)M   <NA>
#4       PC187(A)/664F   PC187(A)     664F   <NA>
```

Note that your expected output doesn't seem to match your input data. For example, for row 1 your expected output for `code_3` gives `"PC664F"`, whereas the relevant input string is `"664F"`. `code_2` for the same row has `"212.5(C)F"` whereas the input string is `"212.5(C)"`. I assume these are errors.

---

### Update

Thanks to @andrew_reece's comment I (think I) now understand your question. Here is an option

```
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    separate(code, c("prefix", "main", "suffix"), sep = c(2, -1), remove = F) %>%
    separate(main, into = paste0("code_", 1:3), sep = "/", fill = "right") %>%
    gather(key, entry, starts_with("code_")) %>%
    filter(!is.na(entry)) %>%
    unite(entry, prefix, entry, suffix, sep = "") %>%
    spread(key, entry) %>%
    select(-row)
```

Explanation: We first `separate` the prefixes and suffixes from `code`, then `separate` the individual components from the main `code` part. We reshape from wide to long, remove `NA` entries, and concatenate each `code` component with the `prefix` and `suffix` before reshaping back from long to wide.

This reproduces your expected output except for `code_2` in row 1.

---

### An alternative

As an alternative approach, it might be more useful to store the pre- & suffixed codes in a `list` column, rather than storing them in a wide format with additional columns `code_1`, `code_2` and so on. This has the advantage that you wouldn't have to hard-code the number of codes you have in column `code`; the following approach will work for *any* number of codes in `code` and only assumes that

1. the first 2 characters of `code` define the `prefix`
2. the last character of `code` is the `suffix`.

```
df %>%
    separate(code, c("prefix", "main", "suffix"), sep = c(2, -1), remove = F) %>%
    transmute(
        code,
        codes_as_list = pmap(
            list(prefix, str_split(main, "/"), suffix),
            function(x, y, z) paste0(x, y, z)))
#                 code               codes_as_list
#1 PC211/212.5(C)/664F PC211F, PC212.5(C)F, PC664F
#2   VC23152(A)/23550F       VC23152(A)F, VC23550F
#3       PC459/460(B)M           PC459M, PC460(B)M
#4       PC187(A)/664F           PC187(A)F, PC664F
```

Note that `codes_as_list` is now a `list` column with the properly pre/suffixed codes, making it easy to operate on the elements with the `purrr::map` machinery.

Comment: I think OP is saying the prefix (e.g. PC, VC) and the suffix (e.g. F, M) should be retained for each of the separated pieces.  That's consistent with OP expected output, except for `code_2` in row 1.

Comment: @andrew_reece Ah, now I see and understand! That'll be a bit more involved than a  single `separate` call. I'm looking into it now...

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, this will give you the prefix and suffix on each separated column:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(prefix = str_extract(code, "^[A-Z]+"),
         suffix = str_extract(code, "[A-Z]$")) %>%
  separate(code, into = c("code_1", "code_2", "code_3"), 
           sep = "/", fill = "right", remove = F) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_1$")), 
            list(~paste0(., suffix))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_2$")), 
            list(~if_else(str_sub(., -1) == suffix, 
                          paste0(prefix, .),
                          paste0(paste0(prefix, .), suffix)))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_3$")), 
            list(~if_else(is.na(.), 
                          NA_character_, 
                          paste0(prefix, .)))) %>%
  select(-prefix, -suffix)

                 code      code_1      code_2 code_3
1 PC211/212.5(C)/664F      PC211F PC212.5(C)F PC664F
2   VC23152(A)/23550F VC23152(A)F    VC23550F   <NA>
3       PC459/460(B)M      PC459M   PC460(B)M   <NA>
4       PC187(A)/664F   PC187(A)F      PC664F   <NA>
```

Comment: Just noticed that this isn't quite right.  In cases where there's no 3rd `code`, the suffix will get repeated.  Looking at an update now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `separate` and `str_extract_all`.  We create a pattern ('pat') that use a regex lookaround to match the position between a `/` followed by number (`[0-9]`) and a second pattern to match character position before `/`.  Using `str_replace_all`, insert the position matched by 'pat' with the first two characters (`substr`) of the string, as well as insert the position before `/` with the last character of string, then use `separate` to split the column into three at the delimiter `/`

```
library(tidyverse)
#pat <- "(?<=\\/)(?=[0-9]+\\(?[A-Z])"
pat <- "(?<=\\/)(?=[0-9])"
pat2 <- "(?=\\/)"
df %>% 
  mutate(code1 = str_replace_all(code, pat, substr(code, 1, 2)) %>% 
  str_replace_all(pat2, substring(code, nchar(code))))%>%
  separate(code1, into = paste0("code_", 1:3), sep="[/]")
#                 code      code_1      code_2 code_3
#1 PC211/212.5(C)/664F      PC211F PC212.5(C)F PC664F
#2   VC23152(A)/23550F VC23152(A)F    VC23550F   <NA>
#3       PC459/460(B)M      PC459M   PC460(B)M   <NA>
#4       PC187(A)/664F   PC187(A)F      PC664F   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very lengthy base R solution using no regex

```
pre <- substr(df$code, 1, 2)
post <- substring(df$code, nchar(df$code))
split_string <- strsplit(df$code, "/")
max_len <- max(lengths(split_string))

df[paste0("code", seq_len(max_len))] <- t(mapply(function(x, y, z) {
    if (length(x) >  2)
     c(paste0(x[1], z), paste0(y, x[-c(1, length(x))], z), paste0(y, x[length(x)]), 
        rep(NA, max_len - length(x)))
    else
     c(paste0(x[1], z), paste0(y, x[length(x)]), rep(NA, max_len - length(x))) 
}, split_string, pre, post))


df
#                 code       code1       code2  code3
#1 PC211/212.5(C)/664F      PC211F PC212.5(C)F PC664F
#2   VC23152(A)/23550F VC23152(A)F    VC23550F   <NA>
#3       PC459/460(B)M      PC459M   PC460(B)M   <NA>
#4       PC187(A)/664F   PC187(A)F      PC664F   <NA>
```

First find the prefix and postfix of every `code` which we want to add on every part of the string, split the string on `"/"` and calculate the number of columns to be added (`max_len`). Using `mapply` we paste `pre` and `post` to each part of the string respectively and fill the spaces with `NA`.